# Applescript application hangs on 10.9 when executing a shell command with administrator privileges

Tags: macos, shell, applescript, admin, osx-mavericks

I'm executing the following line in an Applescript application.

```
set POSIX_path to "/Applications/iPhoto.app"
do shell script "sudo rm -rfv " & quoted form of POSIX_path with administrator privileges
```

The authentification screen pops up as it should but after authenticating the application just freezes upon executing this command. This problems only occurs in 10.9.

When I set the permissions of the folder to be delete to "everyone can read & write" it works.

Does anyone have a clue what has been changed?

EDIT: When I repeat the execution of this script by checking `du -shx /Applications/iMovie.app` it manages to delete a few more files with every try.

```
$ open compiled-applescript.app/
$ du -shx /Applications/iMovie.app
1.4G    /Applications/iMovie.app
-- force quit AppleScript --
$ open compiled-applescript.app/
$ du -shx /Applications/iMovie.app
1.3G    /Applications/iMovie.app
-- force quit AppleScript --
$ open compiled-applescript.app/
$ du -shx /Applications/iMovie.app
1.0G    /Applications/iMovie.app
```

Comment: Its working fine on OS X 10.9 (13A603)

Comment: What happens if you do `sudo rm -rfv /Applications/iPhoto.app` from the terminal?  How long does that take?  `time sudo rm -rfv /Applications/iPhoto.app`

Comment: From the terminal it is working fine and takes like 18 seconds. The problem is strictly related to the execution of the command within AppleScript.

Comment: What happens if you omit the `sudo`?  I suspect the `do shell script` could be waiting for your password to be entered for sudo.  I would think `with administrator privileges` should be sufficient to elevate privileges, without the need for sudo as well.  Unfortunately I currently don't have a mavericks install to test this on.

Comment: I omitted it. Still hangs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After days of trying everything to sort out this problem I finally found what was causing this issue.

It's the verbose-option (-v) of the rm-command. Leaving it out makes the application work flawless again.
Maybe Apple accidently introduced a buffer overflow. I will report this under the problem ID 15309626 I created at Apple's bugtracker. Maybe they'll fix it until the first 10.10 DP :D

Answer (score 2):

Its working fine on OS X 10.9 (13A603)

```
set POSIX_path to "/Users/paragbafna/Desktop/untitled folder"
do shell script "sudo rm -rfv " & quoted form of POSIX_path with administrator privileges
```

[image]

Comment: I also delete from system-folders like ~/Library/, /private/var/db/ (it's an uninstaller).
The problem has been reproduced on three different machines.

Comment: It can easily be reproduced by trying to delete from /Applications.

Comment: I am also using applescript for uninstaller and its working fine. I am deleting folders from /Applications and /Library/Application\ Support.

Comment: Please try it with a system-application like iPhoto.app or iMovie.app!

Answer (score 2):

> Does anyone have a clue what has been changed?

Well yes.. Gatekeeper has changed, that may be the cause..

> When I set the permissions of the folder to be delete to "everyone can read & write" it works.

Did you do this from Finder or from the command line with `chmod 0777`? The latter may delete some attributes that Finder does not remove.

What setting is selected here, on your computer?

[image: OSX - Security & Privacy settings]

If you have a restrictive setting, try "Anywhere" to see if it solves the problem. If this is the cause you may:

1. Have custom command line tools installed, (e.g. MacPorts) or something you compiled yourself (since this is happening on 3 but not all computers and obviously you are not a "generic" user).
2. Your applescript is not being trusted, you can try signing it if possible, otherwise this may work:

   > If the user wants to run an application blocked by Gatekeeper, they have several options. Gatekeeper could, in effect, be turned off by letting it run all applications. **A power user may opt to remove the quarantine attribute or use the spctl command to add a new policy in the security assessment policy subsystem.** - [TrendMicro - about Gatekeeper](http://blog.trendmicro.com/trendlabs-security-intelligence/gatekeeper-on-mac-os-x-10-9-mavericks/)
3. Last resort idea.. Check your disk permissions, re-install Xcode if you use that, maybe the signatures are corrupted.
4. Write a shell script instead, I don't know if it is just about deleting a few files, then you can definitely do it in shell script, or comment to let me know what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: 1. No
2. Turned GateKeeper off, it still hangs
3. done, doesn't work either
4. Tried, still hangs when executed by the AppleScript

Comment: Another thing you should always try with problems on one or a few machines is to create a new user account and see if the issue persists.