# Call Cocoa-function removeItemAtPath through AppleScript

Tags: macos, cocoa, applescript, osx-mavericks, applescript-objc

I want to use the Cocoa-function removeItemAtPath to delete a folder with a path specified in AppleScript part but don't know how to accomplish that through AppleScriptObjC.

Can you help me by giving an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just use AppleScript to delete the folder?

```
set theFile to "path:to:folder:"
tell application "System Events"
    delete disk item theFile
end tell
```

**Edit:**

Based on the comments, you need to do this at the administrator level, and you're able to prompt the user for their credentials. You can put all of that into a shell script.

If you only need the password, using the current user's user name, [this superuser question](https://superuser.com/questions/67765/sudo-with-password-in-one-command-line) shows the shell command is:

```
echo <password> | sudo -S <command>
```

Which makes your code:

```
set pass to text returned of (display dialog "Enter your password:" default answer "password" with hidden answer)
do shell script "echo " & quoted form of pass & " | sudo -S rm 'path/to/file'"
```

If you need to run it under a separate admin user name, you can add in a dialog to get the user name and use the `-u` flag in your shell script:

```
set username to text returned of (display dialog "Enter your username:" default answer "username")
set pass to text returned of (display dialog "Enter your password:" default answer "password" with hidden answer)
set shellscript to "echo " & quoted form of pass & " | sudo -S -u " & quoted form of username & " rm 'path/to/file'"
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Probably because of the missing administrator privileges.

Comment: As far as I know, if you don't have the privileges to delete it, Cocoa won't help you with that.

Comment: when using do shell script you can attach with administrator privileges to gain the necessary privileges. Isn't there something similar for tell application?

Comment: No, but you could just run a shell script instead `sudo rm 'path/to/folder'`. I don't remember the syntax off the top of my head for adding a username/password to that, but it would have to be hardcoded into your script.

Comment: that is not possible. If I could somehow let the user specify his credentials it would be another story.

Comment: If you `do shell script theScript with administrator privileges`, it will pop up a login box.

Comment: Ah that's what you mean. Yeah doesn't work as of OS X Mavericks. Same problem as mentioned here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19547282/applescript-application-hangs-on-10-9-when-executing-a-shell-command-with-admini

Comment: Your solution works but I already coded a small Objective-C-application that uses AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges. It works as well.